# How can I get an element by it's closest matching text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have multiple `h3` which as various text in it. i would like to select an element by it's text content. but i don't receive the exact text matching from back-end.

but i have partly machable text with me. using this how can i select the respected element.

example html :

```
<h3>civil</h3>
<h3>mechanical</h3>
<h3>electrical</h3>
```

js :

```
var text = "civil engineering";

var element = $('h3').closest(":contains('"+text+"')");

console.log(element);
```

here i have `var text = civil engineering` using this i would like to select the `h3` element.

Not only matching this, there is much. i would like to match the text the `closest`.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/vnv90n40/)

Comment: This can be really easy, or really complicated, depends on how you suggest we match the text you've got against the text in the element? Is it always the first word, is it any word, is it a word at all so we can rely on spaces for seperation, is it always the same case (lowercase) etc.

Comment: For just a quick string match, do -> **http://jsfiddle.net/vnv90n40/2/**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*In I understood correctly*

You need to use [`.filter()`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) in combination with [`indexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf)

```
var text = "civil engineering";
var element = $('h3').filter(function(){
    return text.indexOf($(this).text()) != -1;
});
```

```js
    $(document).ready(function() {
      var text = "civil engineering";
      var element = $('h3').filter(function() {
        return text.indexOf($(this).text()) != -1;
      });

      console.log(element.text());
    });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h3>civil</h3>
<h3>mechanical</h3>
<h3>electrical</h3>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `indexOf()` function:

```
var h3 = $('h3');
var str = 'civil engineering';

h3.each(function() {
    if (str.toLowerCase().indexOf($(this).text()) >= 0) {
        $(this).addClass('found');
    }    
});
```

Every `h3` that contains the string you set, gets class `.found`